# Replace string within all occurrences of a string character javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find exact occurrences of all `\n` and `:` and replace the string in between with a specific string.

For example, given this input:

```
 Testing \n string of character \n June,23 2020: the task was completed. \n April,4 2020: All looks \n good
```

The expected result is this:

```
 Testing \n string of character <br><b> June,23 2020</b><br> the task was completed. <br><b> April,4 2020</b></br> All looks \n good
```

```js
const text=`Testing \n string of character \n June,23 2020: the task was completed. \n April,4 2020: All looks \n good`;
const newlineColonRegex = /(\n|:)/g

const replaceWith = '<br><b>'
const newString = text.replace(newlineColonRegex, replaceWith)
console.log(newString)
```

Comment: I edited your question to use code blocks instead of block quotes.  In the process I also removed extra spaces in the `<b>` and `<br>` tags that I believe (based on your code snippet) were accidentally inserted by SO's blockquote code, but wanted to note it here in case those were intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude matching both using an negated character class.

```
\n([^\n:]+):
```

Replace with

```
<br><br>$1<br><br>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AxPhIj/1)

```js
const regex = /\n([^\n:]+:)/g;
const text = `Testing \n string of character \n June,23 2020: the task was completed. \n April,4 2020: All looks \n good`;
const newlineColonRegex = /\n([^\n:]+):/g;

const replaceWith = '<br><br>$1<br><br>'
const newString = text.replace(newlineColonRegex, replaceWith)
console.log(newString)
```

---

If you also want to match it from the start of the string, you could use an anchor instead of a newline `^([^\n:]+:)` and use the `/gm` flags